# how to sort array of dictionaries and display in tableview on click of button action

Tags: ios, uitableview, nssortdescriptor

how to sort this data based up on rating and lowest rate and display in tavleview  ?

```
array(
    {

    "lowest_rate" = 110;
    "max_speed" = 8mbps;
     ratig = "4.5";

},
    {

    "lowest_rate" = 600;
    "max_speed" = 50mbps;
    ratig = 4;
}
```

Comment: which value you want to sort item ?

Comment: lowest rate I need to do

Comment: When language? Swift or Objective-C? There are at least a half-dozen ways to do this, and some of them only apply to Swift.